# If I publish to an Azure WebSite, how can I access my log4net log file?

Tags: azure, log4net

I'd like to start using Azure WebSites, but I'd like to know how I can access the log files that are generated by log4net.  I'm not logging to a SQL server.  The logs that I generate are regular text files -- at least that would be my preference.

Is it possible to access the local file system of your Azure WebSite's host, or will I have to log to some other destination?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I know for Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 you can install Azure Tools and browse files via the Server Explorer in Visual Studio.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee405484.aspx

Also, you can FTP into your site and view/download any files you create.  Login to Azure portal to find your FTP settings. If you login to the Azure management portal, click on your web site/VM and on the dashboard it shows you the FTP links.